# most effective way to parse with nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

What the most effective way to parse with nltk?
I have a big vocabulary and take me age to parse with RecursiveDescentParser.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the NLTK Documentation (parsing)](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html):

> The parser module defines ParserI, a standard interface for parsing texts; and two simple implementations of that interface, ShiftReduceParser and RecursiveDescentParser. It also contains three sub-modules for specialized kinds of parsing:
>   ***nltk.parser.chart*** defines chart parsing, which uses dynamic programming to efficiently parse texts.

You could try the chart parsing sub-module. Hopefully it will be faster. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: No worries. If you're happy with the answer, you should accept it and up-vote it.